# Is it true that $E_j = \lbrace x\in E: \sup\limits_{k\geq j} |f_k(x)| \geq \epsilon \rbrace$

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm doing an assignment an I have one question.

For all $\epsilon >0$, $j \in \mathbb{N}$, let $E_j = \displaystyle \bigcup^\infty_{k=j} \left\lbrace x\in E: |f_k(x)| \geq \epsilon \right\rbrace$. Is it true that $E_j = \lbrace x\in E: \sup\limits_{k\geq j} |f_k(x)| \geq \epsilon \rbrace$.

Fix $j\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $x \in E_j$, then there exists $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}, k_0 \geq j$ such that $|f_{k_0}(x)| \geq \epsilon$. Then $\sup\limits_{k\geq j} |f_k(x)| \geq \epsilon$. So $x \in \lbrace x\in E: \sup\limits_{k\geq j} |f_k(x)| \geq \epsilon \rbrace$.

Conversely, let $x\in \lbrace x\in E: \sup\limits_{k\geq j} |f_k(x)| \geq \epsilon \rbrace$ then we prove $x \in E_j$ by contradiction. Assume $x \notin E_j$, then $|f_k(x)| <\epsilon $ for all $k\geq j$. Then by definition of $\sup$, $\sup\limits_{k\geq j} |f_k(x)| \leq \epsilon$ (And then I cannot show that there is a contradiction here since $\sup\limits_{k\geq j} |f_k(x)|$ can be $\epsilon$).

Thanks alot!

Comment: No. $\left\{x\in E\,:\, \sup_{k\ge j}\lvert f_k(x)\rvert\ge\epsilon\right\}$ also contains the values of $x$ such that there is a subsequence $\{k_h\}_{h=1}^\infty$ such that $\lvert f_{k_h}(x)\rvert\nearrow \epsilon$ and, for all $h$, $\lvert f_{k_h}(x)\rvert<\epsilon$. Therefore there are instances of $$\left\{x\in E\,:\, \sup_{k\ge j}\lvert f_k(x)\rvert\ge\epsilon\right\}\supsetneq \bigcup_{k=j}^\infty \{x\in E\,:\, \lvert f_k(x)\rvert\ge\epsilon\}$$

Comment: I see.. Thank you so much for your support!